# R - Association rules, lhs column is empty

Tags: r

I am using R library `arules` for rules minning.

So first I tried just to see the rules:

```
#Get the rules
rules <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(supp=0.05, conf = 0.05)) #minlen = 2
rules <- sort(rules, by="confidence", decreasing=TRUE)
```

However the `lhs` column is empty:

```
inspect(rules)
 lhs    rhs                support confidence lift
3 {}  => {product=CM,DD,OS} 0.501   0.501      1   
2 {}  => {product=CM,DD}    0.223   0.223      1   
1 {}  => {product=CM}       0.068   0.068      1
```

So I tried to specifically ask for the `lhs` column:

```
rules <- apriori(data=trans, parameter=list(supp=0.05, conf = 0.05),
                 appearance = list(default="rhs", lhs="product=CM,DD,OS"),
                 control = list(verbose=F))
rules <- sort(rules, by="confidence", decreasing=TRUE)
inspect(rules)
```

Unfortunately the output remains same.

One of the reason might be that most of the clients have ~4 products, therefore they might not be any rules, but I find that unlikley.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the format of the data. If I before dump data into .csv and use `read.transactions`, it works correctly.

```
trans = read.transactions("C:/.../basket_analysis_data.csv", format="single",sep = ";", cols = c(2,1))
```

Before I was using direct `ODBC` connection, put data into Data frame and then convert them like this:

```
trans <- data.frame(product = as.factor(qry$product_owned))
trans <- as(trans, "transactions")
```

However use .csv as immediate step is annoying. If anyone can help how to make it work without .csv, I would appreciate it.